# Trying to combine 2 FFmpeg commands

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 2 FFmpeg commands which I need t combine, for the sake of speed.

This one builds a simple slideshow using a list of images located on my remote server.

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist "file,http,https,tcp,tls" -i "Temp/images.txt" -filter_complex "[0]scale=7680x4320,zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.2,max(1.001,zoom-0.0006))':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':fps=30:d=300" -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -shortest "Temp/video.mp4"
```

This one overlays the video we just created aswel as another video (marquee.mp4) and a showwaves effect ontop of a background image, then adds audio. (showwaves effect is tied to said audio)

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 30 -i "Assets/Screens/background.png" -i "Temp/audio.mp3" -filter_complex "movie=Temp/video.mp4[a];movie=Temp/marquee.mp4:loop=0,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[b];[0][a]overlay=570:70[c];[c][b]overlay=570:880[d];[1:a]showwaves=mode=cline:s=254x81:scale=sqrt:colors=0x222222,colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.1,format=yuva420p[w];[d][w]overlay=148:375,scale=1920:1080[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 1:a -movflags +faststart -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -preset veryfast -shortest done.mp4
```

Would it be possible to combine all of this into one command? So that rather than taking the created slideshow video and overlaying, it just generates the slideshow in-place.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -y -framerate 30 -i "Assets/Screens/background.png" -i "Temp/audio.mp3" -f concat -safe 0 -protocol_whitelist "file,http,https,tcp,tls" -i "Temp/images.txt" -stream_loop -1 -i Temp/marquee.mp4 -filter_complex "[2]scale=7680x4320,zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.2,max(1.001,zoom-0.0006))':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':fps=30:d=300[a];[0][a]overlay=570:70[b];[b][3]overlay=570:880[c];[1:a]showwaves=mode=cline:s=254x81:scale=sqrt:colors=0x222222,colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.1,format=yuva420p[w];[c][w]overlay=148:375,scale=1920:1080[outv]" -map "[outv]" -map 1:a -movflags +faststart -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -preset veryfast -shortest done.mp4`

Comment: Gyan, I don't know how you do it. Ofcourse it works perfect :) you've helped me with a lot over the past few months and I really appreciate it. Thank you.